# How to force a Java Applet to Load out of Cache

Tags: java, html, applet, cache-control

My friend and I are developing a little game and we want to share the development stages with our friends. So I made this little page http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~manders8/game.html

Right now it's one .class file that we're updating. But for some reason it always loads the old version. I know there's a way to turn off java caching but my friends aren't that competent. Plus to get people to play your game it should super easy and not requiring like 5 steps with screens shots just to try it out.

I have this is the  tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

Because I thought it might be browser related but that doesn't help.

This is my  code

```
<applet code="com.murderbody.prototype.TitleScreen.class" codebase="http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~manders8/content/" width=640 height=380></applet>
```

Changed from applet to:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.5" width="640" height="380">
     <param name="codebase" value="http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~manders8/content/">
     <param name="code" value="com.murderbody.prototype.TitleScreen.class">
     <param name="cache_option" value="no">
</object>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this inside your Applet tag: `<param name="cache_option" value="no">`

Speaking of Applet tags, they've been obsolete for years; consider using the [`object` tag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#object) instead.

Answer (score 3):

The caching of Java applets may happen at two levels: the browser and the Java plugin. Your problem seems to be with the plugin. I just found this:

http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/appletcaching.html

One approach some people use is resource versioning, i.e. generate a new applet filename for each version (better if you package the applet in a jar file and rename the jar for each new version, e.g. titlescreen-1.2.23.jar). If you have a decent build tool (ant, maven) that can automate this renaming for you, both at the JAR and tag level, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Those tags will do wonders to prevent the *page* from being cached. However, the applet is separate. :)

You need to configure the server to send those headers with the class file itself (if possible, investigate `.htaccess` support).

If that's not possible, but you have access to PHP or some server-side scripting language, you could use something like this:

```
<applet code="com.murderbody.prototype.TitleScreen.class?<?php echo rand(1, 10000);?>" codebase="http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~manders8/content/" width=640 height=380></applet>
```

Edit: Also, R. Bemrose has a good idea. Try adding this to the applet tag:

```
<param name="cache_option" value="no">
```

If that ends up being the solution, be sure to accept his answer :)